# JavaScript: get country name from longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, d3.js

how can I get the country name from longitudes and latitudes using Java Script? Is there any tool or a library I can use?

I have a CSV file that consists the coordinates of tweets. I want to get the country name according to the coordinates of the originating point of the tweet. I'm using JavaScript and d3.js.

Comment: what i actually meant was that coordinates of the csv file are exact originating points of the tweet. So i want to check weather what is the country that includes that longitude and latitude. For example, if i have 121.0523297,14.62194033 i need to check weather what is the country that includes that coordinates.

Comment: You are looking for [*Reverse Geocoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). Available, amongst others, through Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

Answer (score 1):

You can take the data from 
[Lat Long of Countries - Google](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv)

and load to your spreadsheet and write a simple code to load this into an array and use the same.

Comment: Quick and short. Perfect for me, Hopefully, it would be helpful for @user3719977 too.

Answer (score 0):

See the Google Maps API: you can [reverse geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) by entering in a lat/long and getting back and address object which you can parse to find country.

Answer (score -1):

Extending [Sriram Nadiminti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7985192/sriram-nadiminti) answer you can use at [Google Countries CSV](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv) in the console the following script to get all the data from the page as an array of arrays(it will be automatically copied to the clipboard):

```
let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(x => Array.from(x.cells).map(y => y.outerText))
copy(arr)
```

Alternatively, you can use the following script to get them as a CSV string.

```
let text = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(x => Array.from(x.cells).map(y => y.outerText).join(',')).join('\n')
copy(text)
```

If you do not want the header row use:

```
 let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(x => Array.from(x.cells).map(y => y.outerText)).splice(1)
copy(arr)
```

For convenience here is the javascript array https://pastebin.com/xa9S9MEe.

Edit:
Here is the snippet for the data grouped by code:

```
let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(x => Array.from(x.cells).map(y => y.outerText)).splice(1).reduce((acc,x) => {acc[x[0]] = {latitude:x[1], longitude:x[2], name:x[3]}; return acc;}, {})
copy(arr)
```

And the Pastebin https://pastebin.com/8uVAd7Db